# Nginx client certificate authentication: How to exclude an IP address

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have Nginx running as a proxy to a web server and i want to securing Access using TLS/SSL Client Certificates.

This is my ssl config

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl; 
    server_name             www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/server.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/server.key; 
    ssl_client_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/clients/client_ca.pem
    ssl_verify_client on;
```

it works very good - but now i need to allow access to my site without client certificates from one specific IP address.

is there a posibility to do this with nginx?

thank you :-)

Comment: Have you had a look here? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html if you have and are still having problems include what you tried and how it didn't work

Comment: I will try it with the satisfy command. Thank you!

Comment: i tried this [link](http://pastebin.com/Ui6V6S2c) ... but it didnt work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my Solution:

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl; 
    server_name             www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/server.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain/server.key; 
    ssl_client_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/clients/client_ca.pem
    ssl_verify_client       optional;

    # Set global proxy settings
    proxy_read_timeout      360;
    proxy_pass_header       Date;
    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding "";


    location /
    {

    if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4 ) 
       {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.1; 
        break; 
       }

    if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") 
       { return 403; }

    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.1;}

    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
}
```

the ip 1.2.3.4 can acces the website without a client cert :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to create a duplicate `server` container with a different domain name which has `ssl_verify_client` turned off, and some form of `allow`/`deny` scheme in place.

It is possible to set `ssl_verify_client optional` and then manually verify the client, but your clients are prompted for a certificate anyway, so it can be annoying for your users.

Comment: I cant config a second DNS-name - it should be the same DNS-Name from anywhere...